# width exceeds browser window

Tags: html, css, width, viewport

I have looked through previous questions on this topic but after following the advice I could find and looking through the full CSS, I can´t get my head around this...

My width on body, html is set to 100% and I can´t find anything the inflicts on that in terms of padding or such.

Could anyone please point out what the problem is? Might be something really simple that I´m just missing.

Here is the website: [www.niklaskoskela.com](http://www.niklaskoskela.com)

Sorry for not posting just a snippet or so but I really can´t find the problem.

Regards,
Niklas

Comment: So what exactly is the issue as I can't see any problem in Chrome 34

Comment: Your body width is `300%`, if you wonder why ⅔ of your page is not showing

Comment: It looks fine to me in Chrome. Though you do have `width: 300%;` set on your `body`

Comment: It works perfectly for me, I can't scroll sideways, and things look fine. Firefox 30.0a2

Comment: Works perfect in IE8+, however not quite in IE7. Wonder how comes.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to specify where exactly this problem occurs... an example is www.niklaskoskela.com/hkr.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be on your `.nav ul`.  The `margin-right: -8%;` seems to be the issue for me.

For anyone else looking, you will need to click into one of Niklas' projects, such as http://www.niklaskoskela.com/hkr.html

Comment: One possible answer. It's not clear if this is the actual issue but...+1 for looking deeper

Comment: Thank you damienoneill2001, this solved the problem... However, I experience a small small scroll sideways still. Is this a real issue or is it always there, if you know what I mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cheers for the upvote.  It worked for me when I removed it.  Hopefully it points @don_koskela in the right direction anyway!

Comment: also, I can´t seem to get the "prev", "close", "next" icons back to that position without the -8%... any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that  problem is with the div id="wrapper" height.
remove the height:100% and check..

```
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
/*height: 100%;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with damienoneill2001
this is the issue

change your css as follows

```
.nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 1.6%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 40%;
}
```

remove width from body `width:100%` it will take `auto` width

```
body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

lets update some css for navigation to take it right corner

`.nav ul li a.next img {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 15%;
}`

`.nav ul li a.close img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 15%;
}`

`.nav ul li a.previous img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 19%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 15%;
}`

`.nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.6%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 24%;
}`

also please update `hover` classes for `width` and `margin`

Comment: That did it! Thank you Milind More!

Comment: There wouldn´t happen to be a quick trick to move the buttons "previous" "close" and "next" to the right without using -8% like I used earlier?

Comment: everything sorted.. thanks a lot for all your answers